# The hydration issue in nextjs - how to know where and in whivh file / line the issue is coming as console is not showing the line of code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, next.js, jsx, hydration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4iNA.png)
the issue is showing but how can i know in while file or codeline its lying.

I tried by watching my entire code file but unable to find these kind of issue.
The hydration issue in nextjs - how to know where and in whivh file / line the issue is coming as console is not showing the line of code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.